# How to install downloaded Windows 7 theme

Tags: windows-7, installation, themes

I've just download an official Windows 7 theme [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/cityscapes-panoramic-download-theme)

But I cannot install it after download - double clicking will say unknown file type !?

Please help!

Comment: Which version of Windows-7 (Starter, Home Basic, Home Premium, Professional...) ?

Comment: My version is Windows 7 Ultimate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I don't think that this will work on Windows 7. It is a dual screen wallpaper pack which is only supported by Windows 8. Try this one: [African Wildlife Theme](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-NZ/windows/african-wildlife-download-theme). If it works then you simply can't use deskthemepacks. Just themepacks. Hover over the download button to see the filetype.

Okay, so I just double checked and I am correct. There is a [work around though](http://www.labnol.org/software/windows-8-themes/26628/). Give that a shot. [This too](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/d5c8f1c7-638d-4666-8cd7-756c7aac1e77) may be of interest.

Looks like 7zip is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you are not able to use it on windows 7 is because it not for windows 7.
The theme pack is for windows 8 and RT

Quoting the website :

> Bring stunning imagery of some of the most fantastic skylines in the world to your desktop. Hong Kong, London, Vancouver, and Kuala Lumpur will span your screen in full panoramic splendor in this free theme for **Windows 8 and Windows RT** designed to stretch across dual monitors.